# How could I check that a large number has a peak-appearance?

Tags: c++

A number has *peak-appearance*  if its digits, starting from the left side are sorted in ascending
order up to a digit and from that digit on, they are sorted in descending order.

This is my naive approach, but I know it's not 100% correct. My function just doesn't return anything and it's not efficient either.

```
int peak_appearance(int n)
{
    /** trivial case */

    if (n<100)
        return false;

    int current = n%10;
    int previous = (n/10)%10;

    while (n!=0 and current < previous) // starting from the right, checking if we have ascending order
    {
        n = n/10;
        current = n%10;
        previous = (n/10)%10;
    }

    if (n==0) // checking if we have digits on the right side of the peak digit
        return false;

    while (n!=0 and current > previous) // checking descending order
    {
        n = n/10;
        current = n%10;
        previous = (n/10)%10;
    }

    if (n!=0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*just doesn't return anything*"? It looks like it returns something in every branch (even though `return false` in a function returning `int` is not really obvious). What is your problem?

Comment: Regarding your trivial case, it seems like a 1 or 2 digit number could be considered to have a peak-appearance. Your function return type is `int`, but you return a `bool`. That's fine, your `true` and `false` will be converted to `1` and `0` respectively.

Comment: why dont you use the string representation of the number instead it is easier

Comment: Please see [example]. As is, we don't know how you're using this function. We don't know what your input is, We don't know what your expected output is. And we don't know what your actual output is. A `main()` function that calls this would be helpful.

Comment: @NikosM. It would be much easier, but I'm not very familiar with string representations of numbers.